# ESP32-C3 SPI Class documentation/features?

Tags: esp32, spi, documentation

ESP32-C3 has a nice feature called [GPIO Matrix](https://www.espressif.com/sites/default/files/documentation/esp32-c3_technical_reference_manual_en.pdf#iomuxgpio) which allows to map most of it's peripherals to any GPIO pin. And it has feature called IO_MUX which allows direct & faster operations for some of the high speed peripherals, including SPI. The API from ESP-IDF (HAL SDK) provides [some library documentation on SPI functions](https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/latest/esp32c3/api-reference/peripherals/spi_master.html).

But [Arduino-ESP32 core documentation](https://docs.espressif.com/projects/arduino-esp32/en/latest/libraries.html) seems to completely miss SPI library & it's functions. It refers to basic Arduino SPI class, but it lacks description of features ESP32 family has.

I've found [this example for ESP32](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66722386/how-to-use-spi-with-esp32-and-arduino) (note that I'm looking for ESP32-C3 info) which sets SPI pins through SPI.begin method actually.

I've also found [this source](https://github.com/espressif/arduino-esp32/blob/master/cores/esp32/esp32-hal-spi.c) which seems to feature a lot of SPI internal HAL functions. And a C++ [SPI class sources are here](https://github.com/espressif/arduino-esp32/tree/master/libraries/SPI/src). But it's actually doesn't have any useful comments on how to use IO_MUX or allowed values for ::setFrequency() method.

So basically I'm asking for a documentation on ESP32-C3 Arduino specific SPI class features. But to narrow things down **I'm actually looking now how to initialize SPI2 (which is the only generally available SPI master on C3) as IO_MUX at the fastest SPI clock speed possible from the Arduino core/SPI class**. Any suggestions are also welcomed!

Comment: Hi NStorm, I know your post is from a while ago, but for everyone's and anyone's sake: I'm still figuring out how to use the GPIO Matrix with ESP32-C3 and Arduino, but if you are using Arduino with it, then the default pins for SPI2 are defined [here](https://github.com/espressif/arduino-esp32/blob/master/variants/esp32c3/pins_arduino.h). Depending on whether you're initializing the peripheral yourself or a device is doing it for you, there are ways to pass in a different SPI clock speed.